Apply a gradient to a specific word of a sentence - React Native
can't get a linear gradient in a word of a sentences without introducing a line jump
something like <p> some <span>cool</span> text</p> in html were the span is applying a gradient to the text.
I been trying to achieve this effect in a react native app with expo

so far I tried a maskedView with a linearGradient, however that applies the gradient to the whole text, if I try to do like <Text>some <GradientText> cool </GradientText> text </Text> the text inside the gradientText dosnt show at all. and I need the text in the same line. as doing <Text>get<Text> </GradientText> me </Text> <Text>In<Text> gives me lines jump.
this hacky way seems to give me the result exactly as I want it but it only works on android, on iOS I get nothing in the screen:
<GradientText colors={['transparent', 'transparent']}>

    <GradientText colors={['white', 'white']}>
        Get
    </GradientText>
    <GradientText colors={['red', 'blue']}>
        &nbsp;Me
    </GradientText>
    <GradientText colors={['white', 'white']}>
        &nbsp;In
    </GradientText>

</GradientText>


GradientText Component :
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import MaskedView from '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view'
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

export default function GradientText({ style, scale = true, children, colors }) {
    return (
        <MaskedView
            maskElement={
                <Text maxFontSizeMultiplier={scale ? undefined : 1} style={style}>{children </Text>
            }
        >
            <LinearGradient
                colors={colors}
                start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
            >
                <Text maxFontSizeMultiplier={scale ? undefined : 1} style={[style, { opacity: 0 }]}>{children}</Text>
            </LinearGradient>
        </MaskedView>
    )
}


Any time I've tried to do anything not extremely simple with MaskedView it has been a headache. You might have an easier time just using react native skia
